# Infimum/Supremum - End of basic sets question

Tags: real-analysis

I have recently started an online course and this last bonus question for the chapter has me stumped. There are a lot of examples given but they are all much simpler problems and I'm struggling to relate them to this one. Please bare in mind I am a beginner regarding real analysis so where possible please explain your steps, I don't want to know the answer and not understand how I got it. Thanks in advance!

$S$ is a set of real numbers bounded below, $a$ is a real number, $b$ is a positive real number. Let $T = (a+bx : x \in S)$. Show that

$$\inf T = a + b\inf S$$

and state which real number axiom has been used.

Comment: Let $U=\{bx:x\in S\}$; can you show that $\inf U=b\inf S$? Try showing that a real number $y$ is a lower bound for $S$ if and only if $by$ is a lower bound for $U$. Once you’ve figured out how to deal with $U$, dealing with its translate $T=\{a+u:u\in U\}$ shouldn’t be too hard. (It can be done all at once, but you may find it easier to think about if you do it in two steps.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first step is to show that $a + b\inf S$ is a lower bound of the set $T$. That is, you need to show that given any $a+bx \in T$, we have
$$
a + b\inf S \leq a + bx.
$$

Indeed the inequality is true by order properties of real numbers and by the definition of $\inf S$.

The second thing to show is that $a + b\inf S$ is the $\textit{greatest}$ lower bound of $T$. So, given any other lower bound $c$ we want to show that

$$
(*)\;\;\;\;\;\;c \leq a + b\inf S.
$$

How do we show that is true? Well if $c$ is a lower bound of $T$, then

$$
c \leq a + bx
$$

for every $a + b x \in T$. Rearranging, we have then that

$$
\frac{c - a}{b} \leq x 
$$

for every $x\in S$ (it was given here that $b$ was positive, and I assume that means strictly greater than $0$, so it is okay to divide by $b$).

But since $x\in S$ and $\inf S$ is the greatest lower bound of $S$, we have that

$$
\frac{c - a}{b} \leq \inf S.
$$

Rearranging again gives the desired inequality (*).